# Error: getText must be called from the UI thread

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I am trying to enter name,phone and email into a mysql database. I am getting an error in the doInBackground method where the getText needs to be called from the ui thread.

Here is my User Details file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class UserDetails extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser1 jsonParser = new JSONParser1();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPhone;
EditText inputEmail;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://bookit.net16.net//book.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_user_details);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPhone);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);


    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.proceed);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserDetails.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
     String name = inputName.getText().toString();
      String phone = inputPhone.getText().toString();
    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();



        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = JSONParser1.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product


                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Any access to a view must be done on the UI thread, not on another thread or an AsyncTask.  Pass them in as parameters rather than querying for them in doInBackground.  Requesting them in onPreExecute is perfectly ok.

Comment: I am a beginner in android programming. It would be really kind of you to help me with the code

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and extend it of Application and define a Handler on it.

```
public class Global extends Application{
    public static Handler HANDLER = new Handler();
    onCreate(){
    }
}
```

then on code use:

```
Global.HANDLER.post(new Runable(){
     // do anythin with UI you like
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting strings from `doInBackground` get them before you call your async task and pass them as parameters.

```
btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
               String name = inputName.getText().toString();
                String phone = inputPhone.getText().toString();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();

                new CreateNewProduct(name,phone,email).execute();
        }
    });
```

And create a constructor in your Async task

```
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String name,  phone,  email;

        public CreateNewProduct(String param1, String param2, String param3) {
            name= param1;
            phone =param2;
            email = param3;
        }
   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserDetails.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = JSONParser1.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product


                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```